# Object is still a instanceof original constructor after changing constructor property

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am confused as to why after changing constructor property of an object to point to another function still the object is an instance of old constructor

```
//Original Constructor
      function orig_cons() {}

//New Constructor
  function new_cons(){}

 //Adding property to myfun prototype
  new_cons.prototype.x = 1;

 //Invoking a new object of 1st constructor
  var obj1 = new orig_cons();

//check obj1 instanceof 1st constructor
 console.log(obj1 instanceof orig_cons); // true

 //Changing constructor property to point to 2nd function
  obj1.constructor = new_cons;

//check obj1 instanceof 2nd function
 console.log(obj1 instanceof new_cons); // false
```

Also the prototype property of obj1 is still of original constructor's prototype:

```
       console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1)); //orig_cons {}
```

Comment: The `constructor` property has nothing to do with the way `instanceof` works.

Comment: The prototype chain doesn't change when you change the constructor after creation, the objects prototype is still the same.

Comment: clean your code fragment - what does `myfun` have to do with anything there? and use an inline code snippet

Answer (score 0):

instanceof checks the prototype of the object not the constructor , take this example:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

var  p = new Person();

console.log(p instanceof Person); //true

function Func(){}

p.constructor = Func;

console.log(p instanceof Person); // true

Person.prototype = {};

console.log(p instanceof Person); // false
```

notice how changing the prototype affected `instanceof`.

From MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

> The instanceof operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in
>   object's prototype chain.

Comment: Ok. But the prototype property is available on the constructor so how does an instantiated object maintain link to it's original prototype I mean which property, Is it via `__proto__` ?

Comment: object will refer to it with `__proto__`(non standard) , you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to access it n a standards complaint way

Comment: what is the actual usefulness of constructor.prototype if the link is maintained via `__proto__`

Comment: when you call the constructor , `__proto__` of the newly created object  is set to `constructor.prototype`.so, the object get's access to the predefined properties in `prototype` of the constructor.remember that every object has a `__proto__` property linked to it's prototype but only functions get a "implicit" `prototype` property